# Coordinates do not export in UTM format I can use

Tags: coordinates, export

I am trying to export my attribute table so I can view the UTM coordinates, which I need to present in a table in my report. I have got as far as exporting the X and Y coordinates, using the same projection as my project, but the results come in as long strings of numbers that I cannot find information on how to convert. I would really like the output to be as zone, easting, northing (Zone 10U). I have attached the export window and the CSV table result.

[image: Export Window] [image: CSV WIndow]

Comment: Are you looking to determine the UTM zone (1-60) and MGRS grid designation (A-Z ish) for each point? That's very different task than what this solution can generate.  Either way, please add extra columns of the actual coordinate values and your desired format result.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer. Yes, that is what I am doing (looking to determine UTM coordinates for each point). Some of my vectors are lines, some points. The example I provided were line vectors, so there are two points per generated for each end of the line. I'm not sure what you mean by "please add extra columns of the actual coordinate values and your desired format result. "?

Comment: OK, it seems that particular vector is off, as when I import it to google earth it ends up halfway across the world. I tried it with another point vector, and the X Y coordinates returns as lat long, which is a step better, except I would prefer it in UTM